# Copying and Merging two strings in C

Tags: c, merge, copy, c-strings

> ***Note:*** Follow Alk's solution as a guide on your implemetation

I want to create a function that will let the user insert a directory where output files would be saved. My output files will have a static name so I just need the path.

I want to read the path from the user and append it before the name of the output file. So it would be like this:

output name (generated by another function) `outLogFile = "outLogFile.log"`

```
user input = D:\Datasets\some_folder\more_folders

RESULT = D:\Datasets\some_folder\more_folders\outLogFile.log
```

The way I am doing it, I insert the output name on a temp, use `strcpy` to copy the file path into outLogFile and `strcat` to append temp into outLogFile.

Is there a simpler way to do it? A way to merge the two strings into my outLogFile without the use of the temp? A single command to copy the string of path_file before the ouLogFile string, and save it into outLogFile?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char  user_input[100], *path_file,*temp; 
  char *outLogFile = "outLogFile.log";

  printf("Filepath:\n (!Do not inlude filename!)\n");
  gets(user_input);

  path_file = (char*)malloc(strlen(user_input)+1);
  if (user_input[strlen(user_input) - 1]!='\\')
  {
      strcpy(path_file, user_input);
      strcat(path_file, "\\");
  }
  else
  {
      strcpy(path_file, user_input);
  }

  temp = outLogFile;
  strcpy(outLogFile, path_file);
  strcat(outLogFile, temp);

  printf("%s\n%s\n", path_file,outLogFile);
  system("pause");


  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: I could use the `user_input` and `path_file` to `malloc` the `outLogFile` and `strcpy` `strcat` the  string as follows

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char user_input[100]; 
  char *outLogFile;
  char *path_file = "outLogFile.log";

  printf("Filepath:\n (!Do not inlude filename!)\n");
  fgets(user_input,sizeof(user_input), stdin);

  printf("%c\n",user_input[strlen(user_input) - 1]);
  outLogFile = (char*)malloc(strlen(user_input)+strlen(path_file));

  if (user_input[strlen(user_input) - 1]!='\\')
  {
      strcpy(outLogFile,user_input);
      strcat(outLogFile, "\\");
      strcat(outLogFile,path_file);
  }
  else
  {
      strcpy(outLogFile,user_input);
      strcat(outLogFile,path_file);
  }

  printf("%s",outLogFile);
  system("pause");


  return 0;
}
```

However this code takes the \n by hitting the return button and inserts it between the two strings

Comment: The `gets` function is so unsafe it's not funny.

Comment: For starters: You cannot write to where `outLogFile` points as it points to read-only memory, which even if you could write is so "short" to concatenate anything to it.

Comment: `gets()` isn't part of C anymore, as it allows the user to overwrite the program's memory. Use `fgets() ` instead.

Comment: @alk Actually that is not a problem at all. The initial approach was to hardcode the path into `outLogFile` using a `const char *outLogFile`. Then there was the thought of letting the user define the path since we want multiple files to read and multiple outputs.

Comment: I used gets for the testing purposes only, as you see I try to implement the solution as a standalone, to test it works first

Comment: `char *outLogFile = "outLogFile.log"` does *not* allocated any *read-write* memory to `outLogFile`. It makes `outLogFile` point to  `"outLogFile.log"` which is placed into *read-only* memory by the compiler. (In C as opposed to C++) this is *unrelated* to *any* `const` qualification of `outLogFile`. You probably want `char outLogFile[some maximum size] = "outLogFile.log";` Under POSIX `some maximum size`  could be `PATH_MAX`.

Comment: Yeah, because I just need to save the PATH in this variable. How the program handles this information is in a totally different part of the code. The `outLogFile` is purely informational.

Comment: @DavidBowling I can easily leave the initial code as is, hardcode the filepath, I am just asking if there is a way to ask the user to define output directory and save the filepath in `outLogFile`

Comment: `outLogFile` is just a variable that will save information about the PATH, `strcpy` expects a destination where the content will be copied, and the string to be copied, it doesn't need to point to two strings. `strcat` needs to point to two strings. I am guessing that `outLogFile` needs bigger space in order to merge the two strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prefix a string by another string and store the result in a new string the most flexible generic approach would be to use dynamic memory allocation like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char * ps1 = "Hello";
  char * ps2 = " World";

  size_t length_total = strlen(ps1) + strlen(ps2);
  char * ps3 = malloc((length_total + 1) * sizeof *ps3); /* One more for 
                                                            the 0-terminator. */
  if (NULL == ps3)
  {
    perror("malloc() failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  strcpy(ps3, ps1);
  strcat(ps3, ps2);

  /* Use ps3. */
  puts(ps3);

  /* Clean up. */
  free(ps3);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

In your particular case where the code provide a default filename without a path and the use-case is to allow prefixing the filename on run-time one might approach this in a simpler way like this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define LOGFILENAME "some.log"

int main(void)
{
  char logfilepath[PATH_MAX] = LOGFILENAME; /* Just to make sure. */
  char dir[PATH_MAX] = "";

  if (NULL == fgets(dir, sizeof dir, stdin))
  {
    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
      perror("fgets() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  dir[strcspn(dir, "\n\r")] = 0;

  {
    size_t length_dir = strlen(dir);
    if (length_dir > 0 && '/' != dir[length_dir - 1])
    {
      if (PATH_MAX < length_dir)
      {
        errno = EINVAL;
        perror("'dir' to long");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      strcat(dir, "/");
      ++length_dir;
    }

    {
      size_t length_total = length_dir + strlen(logfilepath);
      if (PATH_MAX < length_total)
      {
        errno = EINVAL;
        perror("'dir/filename' to long");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }

  strcpy(logfilepath, dir);
  strcat(logfilepath, LOGFILENAME);

  /* Use logfilepath, . */
  puts(logfilepath);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To not trick this using the `#define` and to not use a third variable go for shifting:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  char logfilepath[PATH_MAX] = "some.log"; 

  {
    char dir[PATH_MAX] = "";

    if (NULL == fgets(dir, sizeof dir, stdin))
    {
      if (ferror(stdin))
      {
        perror("fgets() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    dir[strcspn(dir, "\n\r")] = 0;

    {
      size_t length_filepath = strlen(logfilepath);
      size_t length_dir = strlen(dir);
      if (length_dir > 0 && '/' != dir[length_dir - 1])
      {
        if (PATH_MAX < length_dir)
        {
          errno = EINVAL;
          perror("'dir' to long");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        strcat(dir, "/");
        ++length_dir;
      }

      if (PATH_MAX < (length_dir + length_filepath))
      {
        errno = EINVAL;
        perror("'dir/filename' to long");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      memmove(logfilepath + length_dir, logfilepath, length_filepath + 1);
      memcpy(logfilepath, dir, length_dir);
    }
  }

  /* Use logfilepath, . */
  puts(logfilepath);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: That would be best if you want to store the string in a third variable, that could be easy to implement and won't be asking the question. My question is whether there is a way to merge `str1="Hello"`, `str2 = "world"` into `str2 = "Helloworld"`;

Comment: @D.A: Please see my upodate.

Comment: @D.A: Corrected.

Comment: @alk This could work. It just struck me though of another way to approach this based on your first code. Consult my edited section on the question

Comment: @D.A: Your added approach uses *three* variables as well: two on the stack, one on the heap ... :-)

Comment: @D.A: Also the added code misses to allocate the additional `char` for the final "string"'s `'0'`-terminator.

Comment: @D.A: Also^2 if the user entres nothing by justing hitting Ctrl-D (UNIX) or Ctrl-Z (Windows) this `user_input[strlen(user_input) - 1])` provokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @alk I understand that I am using an extra variable, but hey one less than before, I tested your code and does the same thing with the `\n`. Also just a heads up, you are missing a `#define <string.h>` library for `strlen` to work. Error catching would be my next step of the implementation. :)

Comment: @D.A: Added the missing `#include`. Just as a kind advice: always add as much error checking even in the beginning, it is debugging info for free ... ;-)

Comment: @D.A: Also added a line to chop of the trailing new-line as returned by `fgets()`.

Comment: @alk Noted, even though I use watches and breakpoints a lot. However, in large codes they are a pain in the ass

Comment: @alk Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You may use sprintf() .
Following is the declaration for sprintf() function.
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...)

For Example :

```
sprintf(outLogFile, "%s%s", path_file, outLogFile);
```

You have to care about '\0' character of first string now.

Comment: This leads to undefined behavior, since `outLogFile` points to a string literal in OP code.

Comment: Using `outLogFile` as both an argument to read and write with `sprintf()` is UB  "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined." C11 §7.21.6.6 2